# How to change editor options when switching to diff mode?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, autocmd, vimdiff

I have a few options I like to apply both when Vim is opened in `diff` mode and when it is switched to `diff` mode, e.g., when calling `diffsplit`.

I have the following lines in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=* Wrap set wrap linebreak nolist

function! Set_diff_mode_options()
    syntax off
    set diffopt=filler,internal,algorithm:histogram,indent-heuristic
    autocmd VimEnter * windo Wrap .
    autocmd VimEnter * windo set nofoldenable
    autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
endfunction

" When loading vim in diff mode, e.g. vimdiff
if &diff
    call Set_diff_mode_options()
endif

" When changing to diff mode while vim is open
autocmd OptionSet diff call Set_diff_mode_options()
```

When Vim starts in `diff` mode, all lines of the function are applied correctly. However, when `OptionSet` is activated in an existing Vim windows, the `autocmd`s defined in the function seems to be ignored.

How can I ensure the function works properly in both cases?

**UPDATE 1:**
It looks like replacing `VimEnter` with `CursorMoved` resolves the issue for `diffsplit`, but I suspect it will be inefficient because it performs the same operations many times as I am exploring the diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution you have tried the `OptionSet` triggers the `autocmd` that are linked to `VimEnter`

But it is too late. The `VimEnter` event has already been triggered and it doesn't work.

But for `OptionSet` there are no reason to delay the changes.

I would propose to have two functions:

1. Set_diff_mode_options_post
2. Set_diff_mode_options

The first delays the application of the option after the .vimrc is read and the Windows created for the diff mode.

The second applies directly the options.

```
command! -nargs=* Wrap set wrap linebreak nolist


function! Set_diff_mode_options_post()
    syntax off
    set diffopt=filler,internal,algorithm:histogram,indent-heuristic
    autocmd VimEnter * windo Wrap .
    autocmd VimEnter * windo set nofoldenable
    autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
endfunction

" When loading vim in diff mode, e.g. vimdiff
if &diff
    call Set_diff_mode_options_post()
endif

function! Set_diff_mode_options()
    if &diff
      syntax off
      set diffopt=filler,internal,algorithm:histogram,indent-heuristic
      Wrap .
      set nofoldenable
    endif
endfunction

" When changing to diff mode while vim is open
autocmd OptionSet diff call Set_diff_mode_options()
```

Comment: Explaining why the `VimEnter` didn't work in the OP would improve this answer

Comment: Is it possible to return the focus to the first window, similar to the `wincmd p` line in the question?

Comment: The `OptionSet` is triggered for both windows, we would need a way to identify the "first" one. I don't know how to do that in a reliable way.